# Printing Microsoft Documents/Images with CUPS

Tags: ubuntu, images, microsoft-office, cups

I was wondering if there was an ubuntu package that adds microsoft document support and image support directly from command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can run OpenOffice from the commandline with the `-p`-option. That should be, what you are looking for.

`soffice -p somefile.doc`

Comment: Thanks, are there any CUPS-extensions that would do this automatically?

Comment: Sorry. I don't know.